# Oracle else in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a query look like this

```
select * 
from users
where name = 'A'
 if and only if no result THEN
 name = 'B';
```

I don't want to get the two rows where first row name = A and second row name = B
I need just one of them

is there any way to do that in sql ?

I tried to achive that with not exists or case but couldn't make it work

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since `'A'` is before `'B'` alphabetically then, from Oracle 12, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  name IN ('A', 'B')
ORDER BY name
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

If you do not want to rely on alphabetic ordering then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  name IN ('A', 'B')
ORDER BY CASE name WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

If you want to apply a different `ORDER BY` clause then use a sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   users
  WHERE  name IN ('A', 'B')
  ORDER BY CASE name WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
  FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
)
ORDER BY col1, col2;
```

In earlier versions, you can use the `RANK` analytic function (or `DENSE_RANK`):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT u.*,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE name WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS rnk
  FROM   users u
  WHERE  name IN ('A', 'B')
)
WHERE  rnk = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=eac7de9944b244c9dd9e5e2ef7ec01c3)*

Comment: That was a quick great working answer , thank you